# How do I fix this code smell?

Tags: haskell

I have some code doing explicit recursion, and on top of that it calls the same function twice when it doesn't need to. I figure I can fix the latter, but need help with the former.

```
yesodIdentifier :: Text -> [LDAPEntry] -> Text
yesodIdentifier name ((LDAPEntry _ attributes):_) =
  let (Just eMail) = L.lookup "proxyAddresses" attributes
      partedEmail = L.map (S.splitOn "@") eMail -- now we have   
                                                -- [["garbage:name","domain"]]
  in yesodIdentifier' name partedEmail -- the secondary function is the problem

     where yesodIdentifier' :: Text -> [[String]] -> Text
           yesodIdentifier' nameToMatch ((name:[domain]):rest) =
             if ((unpack nameToMatch) == (sanitized name))
              then (pack (sanitized name)) `append`
                   (pack "@") `append`
                   (pack domain)
              else yesodIdentifier' nameToMatch rest
             where sanitized :: String -> String
                   sanitized dirty =
                     let (garbage:[cleanedName]) = S.splitOn ":" dirty
                     in cleanedName
           yesodIdentifier' name _ = pack "empty identifier"
```

What I am trying to do, is take the (String,[String]) from the LDAPEntry, and reduce it to the email address that matches the name given.

You can see where the recursion is. If I can fix this, I wouldn't have to worry about `yesodIdentifier' name _ = pack "empty identifier"` as this code simply wouldn't be called in the case that the user wasn't in the LDAP database. I just put it there for completion.
I think this is better expressed as a fold, but I can't quite express it correctly in my head. Any ideas?

Comment: You can avoid `pack "..."` by adding `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`, then you can just use `"..."` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be expressed as a filter.  It's not a fold since, if you do recurse, you're recursing on rest and throwing away the earlier entries. You still have to handle the empty list:

```
yesodI nameToMatch list = let result = filter (match(unpack nameToMatch)) list
                              match s1 (s2:[domain]) = s1 == s2
                          in case result of 
                             [] -> "empty identifier"
                             res  -> repack (head res)

repack arg@(name:[domain]) = (pack (sanitized name)) `append`
                   (pack "@") `append`
                   (pack domain)
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of the as-pattern, as I don't see `arg` on the right side.

Comment: "the as-pattern" - you don't understand it because it's non-sensical, that is, not needed. Let's rewrite that line as: "repack (name:[domain]) = ...". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: find would be better since he needs only the first match

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize the email addresses to `(name, domain)` pairs first, use `find` to locate the first one with a matching name, and then `maybe` to decide what to do if you do/do-not find a match:

```
yesodIdentifier :: Text -> [LDAPEntry] -> Text
yesodIdentifier name ((LDAPEntry _ attributes):_) =
  let (Just eMail) = L.lookup "proxyAddresses" attributes
      name' = T.unpack name
      sanitizedEmail = concatMap sanitize eMail -- now we have [("name","domain")]
      empty = "empty identifier"
      nonEmpty (name, domain) = concat [name, "@", domain]
      sanitize s = do
        (dirtyName:[domain]) <- [S.splitOn "@" s]
        (garbage:[cleanedName]) <- [S.splitOn ":" dirtyName]
        return (cleanedName, domain)
  in T.pack . maybe empty nonEmpty . L.find ((name' ==).fst) $ sanitizedEmail
```

This is completely untested, since I don't have all your types available...  I'm hoping that `santize`, in the `List Monad` will discard email address that cannot be broken into `garbage:name@domain`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from ja, rewritten to use find:

```
yesodI name l = intercalate "@" <$> (find ((name ==) . head) $ filter (not . null) l)
```

More readable version

```
yesodI name list = repack <$> find matchName list'
 where list' = filter (not . null) list
       repack = intercalate "@"
       matchName = (name ==) . head
```

Comment: Did you read our little discussion on the superfluous `as` binding?

Comment: Yes, i did not touch repack function, because it is not changed really. But i agree, arg@ is redundant

Comment: i removed the macth function.

Comment: removed repack function. Now it's a one-liner. :)